# updating database with namespace do migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to make changes to my database and am testing it out in my locahost first.  Can anyone see what my mistake is?

In lib/tasks/update.rake:

```
namespace :update do

  desc "Update country"
  task :country_fix => :environment do
    Guideline.where(:hospital => 'Maine Medical Center, Maine').each do |t|
      t.update_attributes(hospital: 'Maine Medical Center')

    end

  end
end
```

When I run

```
rake update:country_fix
```

it's giving an error message which looks like (with --trace)...

```
** Invoke update:country_fix (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute update:country_fix
rake aborted!
Connection refused - connect(2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Rake task itself looks fine.

The `Connection refused` leads me to believe there's a problem connecting to the database using the settings in your `config/database.yml`.  Check to see that the database corresponding to your `RAILS_ENV` is running.  A quick way to test that is:

```
rails db
```

...which will open a database console (`mysql`, `psql`, etc.) based on your current DB configuration and your current `RAILS_ENV`.

Check your `RAILS_ENV` with:

```
echo $RAILS_ENV
```

...and make sure you're really attempting to connect to the expected database.

If `rails db` doesn't work, the fix will depend on what your database is.  If it's PostgreSQL or MySQL or Mongo or most databases, you'll have to launch the server using whatever is appropriate for your system.  If it's SQLite3, there is no server; there may be file permission issues, but it seems like that'd be a different error.

Comment: thanks.  The answer was rather daft.  I hadn't started solr.  Thanks for helping me work it out.

Answer (score 2):

```
Connection refused - connect(2)
```

Did you check your database.yml file? Perhaps you have a wrong configuration of your database server or user.

**Edit:**

Check also your environment. If you run your rake task in your production server for example, you should prefix your rake command like this:

```
RAILS_ENV=production rake update:country_fix
```